# How to determine the type file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Found on the Internet here is such a script, I do not understand whether it works or not? when I change `JQ` to array `$` gives no errors but not working

```js
jQ('.b_article-full a').each(function() {
  if(/.*\.pdf/.test(jQ(this).attr('href'))) {
    jQ(this).before('<i class="b_icons pdf"></i> ');
  }
  if(/.*\.zip/.test(jQ(this).attr('href'))) {
    jQ(this).before('<i class="b_icons zip"></i> ');
  }
  if(/.*\.doc/.test(jQ(this).attr('href'))) {
    jQ(this).before('<i class="b_icons doc"></i> ');
  }
  if(/.*\.docx/.test(jQ(this).attr('href'))) {
    jQ(this).before('<i class="b_icons doc"></i> ');
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores ea pariatur accusantium sit, alias dicta repellat vitae ad ratione numquam.<a href="example.pdf"> Distinctio sapiente unde, at eligendi placeat exercitationem eius eveniet sed?</a>.</p>
```

Comment: it is looking for an element with class `b_article_full`, and descending into the inner `a` tag is checking for its `href` file extension. You miss the first condition for this code to run

Comment: @LelioFaieta thank you... I'm so ashamed ((

Comment: do not worry. See the answer for the proper code :)

Comment: Please mark one answer as correct please if it solved your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p class="b_article-full">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores ea pariatur accusantium sit, alias dicta repellat vitae ad ratione numquam.<a href="example.pdf"> Distinctio sapiente unde, at eligendi placeat exercitationem eius eveniet sed?</a>.</p>
```

You missed the class to be applied to the `p` element for your code to run.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly in your example it would appear that `jQ` is an alias for `jQuery`. You can use the `$` variable instead, as long as you have no other libraries which interfere.

To fix your issue you should amend your selector to find the `a` elements. In your example you need to add a containing element with the class of `b_article-full`. In the below sample I placed this on the `p`.

Also note that a `switch` statement would seem more appropriate than a list of `if` conditions. You can also retrieve the extension by splitting the filename by `.` and getting the last element from the array. Try this:

```js
$('.b_article-full a').each(function() {
  var extension = $(this).attr('href').split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  switch (extension) {
      case 'pdf':
        $(this).before('<i class="b_icons pdf">PDF ICON</i>');
        break;
      case 'zip':
        $(this).before('<i class="b_icons zip">ZIP ICON</i>');
        break;
      case 'doc':
      case 'docx':
        $(this).before('<i class="b_icons doc">DOC ICON</i>');
        break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="b_article-full">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores ea pariatur accusantium sit, alias dicta repellat vitae ad ratione numquam.
    <a href="example.pdf">Distinctio sapiente unde, at eligendi placeat exercitationem eius eveniet sed?</a>.
</p>
```

Note that I placed text within the `i` elements simply so they would appear in the example as I don't have access to the stylesheet you're using.